# Как сделать авторизацию в Play Framework

Tags: java, веб-программирование, playframework

Делаю сайт на Java с PlayFramework 2.3.9!
Надо написать свою авторизацию с наличием групп пользователей(admin/user/guest) и logout без использования инструментов Play.

Answer (score 2):

Разруливать авторизацию и доступ можно как и в Spring фильтрами.

Напишите фильтр, который будет проверять сессию пользователя. Неавторизованных - кидать на страницу входа, у авторизованных - смотреть права и проверять, куда они лезут.

Выход из системы - специальный url, который очистит сессию пользователя или отметит его как незалогиненного, а потом редиректнет на главную.

Comment: отсюда вопрос, как сделать сессию(Session??) и фильтр?

Comment: Дотянуться до сессии, судя по доке, можно через `Http.Context.current().session()`.

Comment: Посмотрите еще сюда: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/JavaGuide4

Answer (score 1):

Курите SpringSecurity

Можно например так:

```
Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

if (!(authentication instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken)) { 
  String currentUserName = authentication.getName(); return currentUserName; 
}
```

Comment: моя ошибка что я не уточнил, я использую play framework и надо написать свою авторизацию

Comment: тогда, вероятно, курить модули авторизации к Play.

Comment: я же написал что надо сделать свою личную авторизацию, без использования инструментов play

Answer (score 1):

Для **play 2.2.2** можно сделать так. Более новый play не проверял.

**Контроллер**

```
public class UserController extends Controller {

   protected static String COOKIE_NAME = "user";

   public static Result login() {
      //Считываем значения из формы:
      DynamicForm requestData = Form.form().bindFromRequest();
      String login = requestData.get("login");
      String password = requestData.get("password");

      if(userExists(login, password)){
         session(COOKIE_NAME, login);
         Logger.info("User found");
      }else{
         Logger.info("User not found");
      }

      return redirect(package.Application.index());
   }

   public static Result logout() {
      session().remove(COOKIE_NAME);
      return redirect(package.Application.index());
   }

   public static boolean isLoggedIn() {
      return session(COOKIE_NAME) != null;
   }

   public static String getSession() {
      return session(COOKIE_NAME);
   }
}
```

**В маршрутах:**

```
POST /login     package.UserController.login()
GET  /logout    package.UserController.logout()
```

Сессия в PLAY хранится в кукисах на стороне клиента, то есть она видима для пользователя, но ее нельзя отредактировать (целостность контролируется).
Если не нравится, что пользователи могут видеть, что именно хранится в сессии - можно шифровать значения перед записью каким-нибудь AES. (У меня вообще там Java объект в Json формате шифрованный AES)

Если не нравится сам метод хранения, можно создать в БД табличку с сессиями, на метод login() сохранять в нее значения и sessionid. и пользователю уже конкретно писать в кукис sessionid вместо user.

Comment: а как при переходе на другую страницу проверять авторизирован ли пользователь?

Comment: В шаблоне  **@if(UserController.isLoggedIn()){}** В другом контроллере **if(package.UserController.isLoggedIn()){}** или **import package;** и просто использовать **UserController** как класс со статическими методами